# Product not displayed after migartion in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I Migrate magento to 1.9.2.4.
After migration my Product are not displaying on front-end.

I got message : 
There are no products matching the selection.

Please suggest what can "I do.

Comment: reindex data and try again

Answer (score 1):

If products are not shown please check the following:

- products are active
- products are assigned to your website
- products are assigned to a category
- products are in stock (or stock management disabled)

Answer (score 0):

enable system log.
and check log file any error display or not. sometimes its block permission issue

Answer (score 0):

I dont know from which version you upgraded magento to 1.9.2.4

But please follow below steps

1) reindex the data from `System->Index Management`

2) `flush cache storage` from `System->Cache Management`

and try again and look at frontend.